# Why was the USS Vincennes in the Persian Gulf in 1988?

Tags: united-states, military, persian-gulf

At 3 July of 1988 a USS Vincennes was in the Persian gulf. Why US navy was in the Persian gulf at that time?

### Edit

I'm seeing my question is flagged as it is trying to

> promote or discredit a specific political cause,
> group or politician.

I should clarify that it's far from the case. I'm not asking this question to implicitly condemning the shooting of the Iranian plane or make a discussion related to that tragic incident. Honestly I was reading about that event and I just wanted to know what was the mission of USS Vincennes at the Gulf at that time.

[source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iran_Air_Flight_655)

Comment: This isn't on topic here but the wilki has your answer "USS Vincennes had been deployed to the Persian Gulf on short notice to compensate for the lack of AWACS cover."

Comment: There wouldn't be anything wrong with asking about this tragic incident (courtmartials, compensation paid, jail time, etc...).  But you are not really doing that, are you?  Looks more like "find out what that nasty USN ship ended up doing".

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica Actually my question is about the reason the navy was it that place. I just wanted to know what was the mission of that ship in the gulf at that time.

Comment: Well, starting the Q out by stating the ship shot the airliner and *then* asking what it was doing there would make for a lot less pushy looking question.  I mean, shooting the airliner is the primary reason Vincennes location on that date is of any interest, is it not?  And, the `Background` section of the wiki page goes into what the USN was up to in the area, so you must have seen it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this appears to be a non-political question about military history.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen because the question why the US government sent its ship to those water **is** a political question.

Comment: @ccprog The decision to send a ship or other military deployment is generally not a political decision and is generally a military one to support the needs of what it is doing. The US navy has been maintaining a presence in the Persian Gulf since the end of WW2 and having ships there isn't an unusual thing.

Comment: @JoeW Kuweit asking the US for protection and the US granting it are political decisions. The rest of blobbymcblobby's answer, I agree, has not much relevant to add. Point is, don't blame a fair question for inappropriate answers.

Comment: @ccprog You should have put that in your comment and explained why you think that the US moving a ship the the Persian Gulf which they have been doing regularly since WW2 is different.  What suddenly makes this ship movement a political one when it is something that happens all the time?

Comment: @ohwilleke: Should be migrated to H.SE, I think, primarily due to the age of the event. https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5836/cutoff-between-politics-and-history Although it might be closeable there as "too basic"...

Comment: @ccprog: https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5836/cutoff-between-politics-and-history The OP hasn't made it clear why the event is relevant today.

Comment: @JoeW You should consider that I wasn't aware of the fact that US navy was present in the Persian Gulf since the WW2.

Comment: I had addressed that comment to someone else and I wasn't aware of it until I googled information on the presence of the US in the gulf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answers the following question directly:

> *I just wanted to know what was the mission of USS Vincennes at the Gulf at that time.*

> *Why the USS Vincennes was in the Persian gulf in 1988?*

In short, USS Vincennes was a **replacement** assignment. She was **not originally assigned** to the Gulf **at all**.

On 14 April 1988, the Oliver Hazard Perry guided missile frigate **USS Samuel B. Roberts struck a mine** while deployed in the Persian Gulf as part of Operation Earnest Will.

**Operation Earnest Will**, which was in effect from 24 July 1987 to 26 September 1988, was the American military protection of Kuwaiti-owned tankers from Iranian attacks in 1987 and 1988. Under the command of the USN 7th Fleet which had primary responsibility for combat operations in the Persian Gulf, the ships (up to 30) mostly consisted of Carrier Battle Groups, Surface Action Groups and ships from the Pacific's Third and Seventh Fleets and the Mediterranean-based 6th Fleet.

This was in response to a number of issues - the tanker war, from 1984, was intensifying, the USS Stark (another Oliver Hazard Perry guided missile frigate) had been struck with loss of life in May 1987.

Kuwait had officially requested US protection in the region.

So USS Samuel B. Roberts was originally part of this operation and had only just arrived in the Gulf when she hit a mine.

Evidence of the origins of the mines led to a major US retaliation on Iranian forces resulting in heavy losses for Iran. So the atmosphere, as it were, was extremely tense at this time.

With her keel broken, the **Roberts was crippled** and a **replacement was needed**.

Vincennes was actually in a different part of the world, taking part in **FleetEx 88-2**, a major Cold War exercise, as part of a carrier battle group exercise held off **southern California**.

The Operation Earnest Will commanders deemed this an opportunity to deploy a more effective vessel in the operation - the **AEGIS** (at the time, a very advanced integrated war-fighting system - the tell tale signs are the big flat panels on the superstructure, which is the phased array) equipped cruiser is far more capable than the smaller frigate that had just been lost, so Vincennes was called for.

After stopping off at San Diego she set sail for the Gulf, where she would serve as **guard ship** at the **Straits of Hormuz**.

https://www.strausscenter.org/strait-of-hormuz-tanker-war/

https://digital-commons.usnwc.edu/nwc-review/vol73/iss2/8/

https://www.npr.org/2019/08/01/747170673/remembering-the-tanker-war-of-the-1980s

https://www.cia.gov/resources/csi/studies-in-intelligence/volume-60-no-3/fighting-iran-intelligence-support-during-operation-earnest-will-1987-88/

https://www.history.navy.mil/content/history/nhhc/about-us/leadership/director/directors-corner/h-grams/h-gram-018/h-018-1.html

https://www.history.navy.mil/content/history/nhhc/browse-by-topic/ships/modern-ships/uss-samuel-b--roberts--ffg-58-.html

https://www.history.navy.mil/content/history/nhhc/about-us/leadership/director/directors-corner/h-grams/h-gram-020/h-020-1-uss-vincennes-tragedy--.html

https://www.usni.org/magazines/proceedings/2018/july/human-machine-team-failed-vincennes

https://www.history.com/this-day-in-history/u-s-warship-downs-iranian-passenger-jet

Answer (score 1):

That shouldnt be too hard to figure out.

[The Tanker Wars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tanker_War#1988)

> The Tanker War was a protracted series of armed skirmishes between Iran and Iraq against merchant vessels in the Persian Gulf and Strait of Hormuz from 1984 to 1988. The conflict was a part of the larger Iran–Iraq War.

I would "guess" Vincennes was:

a) carrying out a right to navigate in international waters.  Persian Gulf is one such body of water, right?

and

b) escorting tankers

From your own source:

> On 3 July 1988, Vincennes, under the command of Captain Will Rogers III, was on patrol when it was reported that **Iranian Revolutionary Guard gunboats had attacked a Pakistani merchant vessel.** Vincennes deployed one of her helicopters to investigate. Shortly thereafter, Rogers ordered his ship to move off station 50 miles (80 km) to the north.

[The actual issue: USN Vincennes shot down an Iran Air A300, killing 290 people](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iran_Air_Flight_655)

> Iran Air Flight 655 was a scheduled passenger flight from Tehran to Dubai via Bandar Abbas that was shot down on 3 July 1988 by two SM-2MR surface-to-air missiles fired by USS Vincennes, a guided-missile cruiser of the United States Navy. The missiles hit the aircraft, an Airbus A300, while it was flying its usual route over Iran's territorial waters in the Persian Gulf, shortly after the flight departed its stopover location, Bandar Abbas International Airport. All 290 people on board were killed.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iran_Air_Flight_655) The attack occurred during the Iran–Iraq War, which had been continuing for nearly eight years. Vincennes had entered Iranian territorial waters after one of its helicopters drew warning fire from Iranian speedboats operating within Iranian territorial limits.[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USS_Stark_incident)[4][5][6]

> The reason for the downing has been disputed between the governments of the two countries. According to the United States, the Vincennes crew had incorrectly identified the Airbus as an attacking F-14 Tomcat, a U.S.-made jet fighter that had been part of the Iranian Air Force inventory since the 1970s. While the F-14s had been supplied to Iran in an air-to-air configuration,[7][8] the Vincennes crew had been briefed that the Iranian F-14s were equipped with air-to-ground ordnance.[9] The U.S. military asserts that the Vincennes had made ten attempts to contact the aircraft both on military and civilian frequencies but received no response.[10] According to Iran, the cruiser negligently shot down the aircraft, which was transmitting IFF squawks in Mode III, a signal that identified it as a civilian aircraft, and not Mode II as used by Iranian military aircraft.[11][12] The event generated a great deal of criticism of the United States. Some analysts blamed the captain of Vincennes, William C. Rogers III, for overly aggressive behavior in a tense and dangerous environment.[10][13] In the days immediately following the incident, President Ronald Reagan issued a written diplomatic note to the Iranian government, expressing deep regret.[14] When Reagan was directly asked if he considered the statement an apology, he replied, "Yes."[14] However, the U.S. continued to insist that Vincennes was acting in "self-defense".

Seems right out of today's headlines, eh? Iran shooting down an [Ukrainian airliner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ukraine_International_Airlines_Flight_752) and the Houthis carrying out piracy on the high seas.  Thanks for the history lesson.

p.s. Possibly a factor in Vincennes' captain's overreaction was the previous year's [USS Stark incident](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USS_Stark_incident), which involved an *Iraqi* jet:

> The USS Stark incident occurred during the Iran–Iraq War on 17 May 1987 in Persian Gulf, when an Iraqi jet aircraft fired two Exocet missiles at the U.S. frigate USS Stark. A total of 37 United States Navy personnel were killed or later died as a result of the attack, and 21 were injured.

> **Captain Brindel was recommended for court-martial but was ultimately only reprimanded and relieved of duty**.[10] It was found that Stark was 2 miles (3.2 km) outside the exclusion zone and had not violated neutrality as the Iraqis claimed.[11] Iraq apologized,[12] and Saddam Hussein said that the pilot mistook Stark for an Iranian tanker.

Comment: Downvoted because your answer only has to offer guesses, but takes a lot of effort to exhonorate the American side from blames.

Comment: Look at my comment under Q. *(courtmartials, compensation paid, jail time, etc...)*  That seem like excuses?  Anyway, these are not guesses: Vincennes was, until it entered Iranian waters, involved in a freedom of navigation and ship protection mission.  I don't think much of Vincennes activities, from shooting, rather than arming their CIWS (which Stark had neglected IIRC) and especially going into Iranian territorial waters.  So, yeah, the exoneration bit, well, that's certainly your call to make, innit?  But where do I do re. Vincennes acts?  Re. the patrolling, yes, full support there.

Comment: The "guess" was for sarcastic effect, in response to a Q phrased in a needlessly pushy fashion.  Everyone who has a clue about that period knows exactly why it was there.  The only real question is the exact circumstances of the shooting, whether the Americans were careful enough - they were not - and what  compensation was offered.  The mission itself?  Not so much.

Comment: Exactly my point. The question was edited and is no longer pushy at all, "everyone knows" is not a qualified answer, and now you openly say you support the American military. That's "promote or discredit a specific political cause, group or politician."

Comment: I said I supported that particular mission, avoiding neutral civilian ships being shot up.  You have a problem with that?  Piracy off Somalia OK?  Houthis targeting civilian ships good?  I did **not** say I supported the Vincennes' actions. I would support a mission to protect ships off Yemen.  Not so much one to target Yemeni infrastructure to dissuade, for example.  Anyway, you are welcome to have your opinions.  But don't misrepresent my statements.